# Fastest way to "grep" big files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have big log files (from 100MB to 2GB) that contain a (single) particular line I need to parse in a Python program. I have to parse around 20,000 files. And I know that the searched line is within the 200 last lines of the file, or within the last 15000 bytes.

As it is a recurring task, I need it be as fast as possible. What is the fastest way to get it?

I have thought about 4 strategies:

- read the whole file in Python and search a regex (method_1)
- read only the last 15,000 bytes of the file and search a regex (method_2)
- make a system call to grep (method_3)
- make a system call to grep after tailing the last 200 lines (method_4)

Here are the functions I created to test these strategies :

```
import os
import re
import subprocess

def method_1(filename):
    """Method 1: read whole file and regex"""
    regex = r'\(TEMPS CP :[ ]*.*S\)'
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        txt = f.read()
    match = re.search(regex, txt)
    if match:
        print match.group()

def method_2(filename):
    """Method 2: read part of the file and regex"""
    regex = r'\(TEMPS CP :[ ]*.*S\)'
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        size = min(15000, os.stat(filename).st_size)
        f.seek(-size, os.SEEK_END)
        txt = f.read(size)
        match = re.search(regex, txt)
        if match:
            print match.group()

def method_3(filename):
    """Method 3: grep the entire file"""
    cmd = 'grep "(TEMPS CP :" {} | head -n 1'.format(filename)
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print process.communicate()[0][:-1]

def method_4(filename):
    """Method 4: tail of the file and grep"""
    cmd = 'tail -n 200 {} | grep "(TEMPS CP :"'.format(filename)
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print process.communicate()[0][:-1]
```

I ran these methods on two files ("trace" is 207MB and "trace_big" is 1.9GB) and got the following computation time (in seconds):

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|          |   trace   | trace_big |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
| method_1 | 2.89E-001 | 2.63      |
| method_2 | 5.71E-004 | 5.01E-004 |
| method_3 | 2.30E-001 | 1.97      |
| method_4 | 4.94E-003 | 5.06E-003 |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

So method_2 seems to be the fastest. But is there any other solution I did not think about?

### Edit

In addition to the previous methods, Gosha F suggested a fifth method using mmap :

```
import contextlib
import math
import mmap

def method_5(filename):
    """Method 5: use memory mapping and regex"""
    regex = re.compile(r'\(TEMPS CP :[ ]*.*S\)')
    offset = max(0, os.stat(filename).st_size - 15000)
    ag = mmap.ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY
    offset = ag * (int(math.ceil(offset/ag)))
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_COPY, offset=offset)
        with contextlib.closing(mm) as txt:
            match = regex.search(txt)
            if match:
                print match.group()
```

I tested it and get the following results:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|          |   trace   | trace_big |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
| method_5 | 2.50E-004 | 2.71E-004 |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: You might want to use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to measure code snippets like this.

Comment: In fact my tests are run thanks to >>> python -m timeit 'from fast_read import method_1 as method ; method("trace")'

Comment: I wonder how these (5) would do if you didn't have the constraints of just reading the last 15,000 bytes or 200 lines. ie: if you just used it for a 'typical grep' type of scenario and you searched in both types of sizes of files..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may also consider using memory mapping ([mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) module) like this

```
def method_5(filename):
    """Method 5: use memory mapping and regex"""
    regex = re.compile(r'\(TEMPS CP :[ ]*.*S\)')
    offset = max(0, os.stat(filename).st_size - 15000)
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_COPY, offset=offset)) as txt:
            match = regex.search(txt)
            if match:
                print match.group()
```

also some side notes:

- in the case of using a shell command, [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) may be in some cases orders of magnitude faster than grep (although with only 200 lines of greppable text the difference probably vanishes compared to the overhead of starting a shell)
- just compiling your regex in the beginning of the function may make some difference

Comment: Great solution: it improves the computation time compared to method_2. Just a note: in `mmap.mmap`, offset has to be a multiple of mmap.ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY, so I added a round to its nearest upper multiple.

Answer (score 2):

Probably faster to do the processing in the shell so as to avoid the python overhead. Then you can pipe the result into a python script. Otherwise it looks like you did the fastest thing.

Seeking then regex match should be very fast. Method 2 and 4 are the same but you incur the extra overhead of python making a syscall.

Comment: On a recent parsing challenge (I had to scan the entire file, not just a portion) my first version in bash, which was easy to write as a combination of awk, sed, gsed, and grep, took a minute or so per file. It scaled badly and I used tmp files to improve it by 10x. Still too slow. My final version in Python (closest to method 1 here but **not** reading whole file into memory) ran in less than 3 minutes, probably 50x or more faster than the original approach in bash. It came down to making a single pass through the file and being very selective on extracted data.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be in Python? Why not a shell script?
My guess is that method 4 will be the fastest/most efficient. That's certainly how I'd write it as shell script. And it's got the be faster than 1 or 3. I'd still time it in comparison to method 2 to be 100% sure though.

Comment: I need to get the value in my Python program, as it is just a small part of a computation code management code written in Python.

Comment: In that case I'd still consider writing it as a shell script. Depending on performant you find the Python implementations. You could for example have a shell script that finds the line, and writes the value to another file. Then have Python call the script, and read the value out of the file.

Comment: Would it be faster to run an external script and get its return than to run the command wih subprocess?

Comment: Method 4 is fastest in shell because method 2 can't be implemented in shell. Method 2 is fastest in python because it doesn't involve spawnig subprocesses.

Comment: I just made the test: the results are equivalent to those of method_4.

Comment: @Simpom, it could be. For example you can have a file that contains a list of all the files that you need to search, and a script that reads all of those file names in and iterates over them. Then, if it finds the line it `cat`s the result into an output file. That would probably be the fastest way to search the text, and you have the added bonus of only having to spawn a single subprocess.

Comment: @mouviciel, is that necessarily true? I seem to remember that Python's seek from file end doesn't really seek from the end of the file, and is not as efficient as you'd expect it to be.

Comment: I expect nothing, I observe time measures provided in question.